# How can I limit my list input to only 4 items in dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart

Am creating a list of questions based on the choice chip in dart, the selected chip is added to the list.

I don't know how to go about it

Comment: Have your problem is Solved ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

**I'm Trying to Solve your problem:**

**Code:**

```
List<String> list = [];

void addItemToList(String item) {
  if (list.length < 4) {
    list.add(item);
  }
}
```